# Javascript WebSocket not connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, client

I start with WebSockets and Node, and my first client not connecting with my server.

Server:

```
var http = require('http');
var onRequest = function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('aaaaa\n');
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(9090, '127.0.0.1');
```

Client:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvasHandle = false;
    var bufferHandle = false;
    var bufferImage = false;
    var WIDTH = 400;
    var HEIGHT = 400;
    var lastTime = false;
    var currentTime = false;
    var dt = false;
    var unitStep = 2;

    var unitX = new Object();
        unitX.name = "John"; 
        unitX.x = 10;
        unitX.y = 10;
        unitX.bodyWidth = 20;
        unitX.bodyHeight = 20;
        unitX.bodyColor = "rgb(0,0,255)";

    var update = function(dt) {
    }
    var draw = function() {
        //Clear Buffer
        bufferHandle.fillStyle = "rgb(200,200,200)";
        bufferHandle.beginPath();
        bufferHandle.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        bufferHandle.fill();

        //Draw Objects

        bufferHandle.fillStyle = unitX.bodyColor;
        bufferHandle.beginPath();
        bufferHandle.rect(unitX.x, unitX.y, unitX.bodyWidth, unitX.bodyHeight);
        bufferHandle.fill();

        //Double Buffer
        bufferImage = bufferHandle.getImageData(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        canvasHandle.putImageData(bufferImage,0,0);
    }
    var gameLoop = function(){
        currentTime = new Date();
        elapsedTime = currentTime.getTime() - lastTime.getTime();

        update(elapsedTime);
        draw();

        lastTime = currentTime;
    }

    $(document).keypress(function(evt){

        switch(evt.which){
            case 100: //d
                unitX.x += unitStep;
                break;
            default:
                //alert(evt.which);
        }
    });

    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:9090/");

    socket.onerror = function(error) {
        alert('Error');
    };
    socket.onopen = function(event) {
        alert('Connected');
    };
    socket.onmessage = function(event) {

    };
    socket.onclose = function(event) {

    };
    //Create Canvas 
    bufferHandle = document.createElement('canvas');
    bufferHandle.width = WIDTH;
    bufferHandle.height = HEIGHT;
    bufferHandle = bufferHandle.getContext('2d');

    canvasHandle = document.getElementById('game');
    canvasHandle = canvasHandle.getContext('2d');
    lastTime = new Date();
    setInterval(
        function(){
            gameLoop();
        }, 50
    );

};
```

I have tried everything but did not connect to server. When I try to connect from url 'localhost:9090' it work and back to be 'aaa'. But whet I use my client script it gets an error.

Comment: Your server needs to support the webSocket protocol in order to accept an incoming webSocket connection  It appears like your server is just a plain http server which does not support webSocket connections.  Also, if you are trying to connect to a different domain/port than your web page was loaded from, you will also need to support CORS so that you can make a cross origin connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is just an HTTP server. You must use a WebSockets server on top of HTTP server.

The most common way of doing this is to install the package `ws` with `npm`. You can find the source code and instructions here: https://github.com/websockets/ws

Also, you can use `socket.io`. It uses WebSockets along with other methods to allow almost any browser (old and new) to use WebSockets (or a substitute of them). Here you have an example: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/